# Read and process multiple json files in python

Tags: python, json, django

I'm trying to process many json files with user input.
If there are three indentical data ["a","a","a"] in GeneListA, I suppose it is going to run the code three times with 
jsonurl = "http://abc.def/a/format=json"

However, I got the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/me/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/me/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/Desktop/Project/gsea/analysis/views.py", line 49, in result
    for gene in data[0][gidA]:
KeyError: 'NC_000913\r\nNC_000913\r\nNC_000913'
```

And here is my code:

```
AGOAnnos = []
for genefromlist in GeneListA:
    jsonurl = "http://abc.def/"+genefromlist+"/format=json"
    print(jsonurl)

    with urllib.request.urlopen(jsonurl) as url:
        data = json.loads(url.read().decode())

    for gene in data[0][gidA]:
        for anno in data[0][gidA][gene]:

            if type(anno) is dict:
                GOAnno = re.search(r'GO:\d+',anno["ID"])
                if GOAnno:
                    AGOAnnos.append(GOAnno.group())

            elif type(anno) is str:
                GOAnno = re.search(r'GO:\d+',anno)
                if GOAnno:
                    AGOAnnos.append(GOAnno.group())
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't find what are the values of variables (gidA / gene) in your code.
The error raised because the in the data response there is no key with gidA